# Mark error in IRemoteFile in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, remote-server

I write an Eclipse plug-in that marks errors in files. With `IFile`, this is pretty easy, as one can use the `createMarker()` method.

Now I also have `IRemoteFile` elements. As `IRemoteFile` does not implement `IResource`, I cannot call `createMarker()`. Does anybody know a way to achieve a similar result with `IRemoteFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [markers](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html) can only be created for resources.

[`IResource#createMarker(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html)

There is a long standing [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22284) but it seems that there are no plans to work on this.

And I don't see how this could be worked around, except maybe that you create *shadow resources* for each `IRemoteFile` that you want to have markers for.

And of course synchronize the resources' content with the remote file so that the markers can be opened in an editor, etc.